# Removing save,cancel options while pressing previous button blackberry

Tags: blackberry

Whenever i press the Back or previous button on the blackberry simulator everytime it asks whether to save cancel or discard? I don't want that to be shown at all .Please anybody help me to remove that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ok you can do the following to remove it.

```
    protected boolean onSavePrompt() {
            return true;
    }
```

You consume the event by returning true. Hence the prompt is not shown